# Okipa :configParams with data from controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I'm using Okipa for tables and I'm wondering if I can pass data from the controller into the `configParams` instead of just an integer.

Something like this:

```
<livewire:table :config="App\Tables\GroupUsersTable::class" :configParams='["user_id" => "{{ $user->id }}"]'/>
```

Instead of:

```
<livewire:table :config="App\Tables\GroupUsersTable::class" :configParams='["user_id" => 2]'/>
```

I already tried some ways and I can't achieve it, thanks if someone can help.